# Autofilter with .Sheets(Array)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste, autofilter

This is my first post on Stack Overflow.

I have an Excel file that contains multiple sheets with data. Sheet "Emailer" contains buttons to hit the macro. The macro is working fine, while running it copies the defined sheets into new workbook and create an outlook email with attachment.

All is working fine, I would need a filter on a specific column to filter the data before copy and past into new workbook. Currently, all the data with no filter is copying. The specific column (M) is available in all 4 sheets that I want to filter (basis the value available under it) and copy paste.

Below is my code i am struggling with to achieve what i want.

Request to help and applgoies if i havent follow any rule of posting the question.

Thansk in advance.

```
Sub MIS_Mail()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim StrSignature As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
    Dim TempWindow As Window

    
    Set ws = Sheets("Emailer")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("GROW MONEY")
    Set rng = Nothing
    'Set rng2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:M34").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B18:I33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    With Sourcewb
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
        .Sheets(Array("GROW MONEY", "Tranche wise details", "All products Deal limit status", "Delinquency")).Copy ' here i want to filter the data in all three sheets before copy
    End With

    'Close temporary Window
    TempWindow.Close
    
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
            
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
        For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
            sh.Select
            With sh.UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).Select
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Destwb.Worksheets(1).Select
        Next sh
    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = Sourcewb.Name


    strBody = "<font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"" color=""#1F497D"">" & "Dear All," & "<br> <br>" & _
           "Please find attached MIS Report as on " & Format(ws2.Range("B1").Value, "DD-MMM-YY") & "." & "<br><br>" & "</font>"
    
       
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    On Error Resume Next
           
With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
           
    With OutMail
        .To = ws.Range("C5").Value
        .CC = ws.Range("D5").Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ws.Range("E5").Value
        .HTMLBody = strBody & RangetoHTML(rng) '& RangetoHTML2(rng2) & vbNewLine '& StrSignature '& Signature
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
.Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

 

Function RangetoHTML2(rng2 As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng2.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML2 = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML2 = Replace(RangetoHTML2, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I have tried to do something with Autofilter with array() but not luckm here is the edited code:

```
Sub MIS_Mail()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim StrSignature As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
    Dim TempWindow As Window
    Dim CatSites As String
        
    Set ws = Sheets("Emailer")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("GROW MONEY")
    Set rng = Nothing
    'Set rng2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:M50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B18:I33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    
     
    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    With Sourcewb
    
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
         CatSites = "GROW"
         
        .Sheets(Array("GROW MONEY", "Tranche wise details", "All products Deal limit status", "Delinquency")).AutoFilter
        .Sheets(Array("GROW MONEY", "Tranche wise details", "All products Deal limit status", "Delinquency")).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=CatSites
        .Sheets(Array("GROW MONEY", "Tranche wise details", "All products Deal limit status", "Delinquency")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        

                
      
    End With

    'Close temporary Window
    TempWindow.Close
    
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
            
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
        For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
            sh.Select
            With sh.UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).Select
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Destwb.Worksheets(1).Select
        Next sh
    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = Sourcewb.Name


    strBody = "<font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"" color=""#1F497D"">" & "Dear All," & "<br> <br>" & _
           "Please find attached MIS Report as on " & Format(ws2.Range("B1").Value, "DD-MMM-YY") & "." & "<br><br>" & "</font>"
    
       
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    On Error Resume Next
           
With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
           
    With OutMail
        .To = ws.Range("C2").Value
        .CC = ws.Range("D2").Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ws.Range("E2").Value
        .HTMLBody = strBody & RangetoHTML(rng) '& RangetoHTML2(rng2) & vbNewLine '& StrSignature '& Signature
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
.Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
  
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with similar code as later in your Sub (usually not needed to post your entire sub if it's this long, just the bit you're struggling with)

```
Sub MIS_Mail()

    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, nsh As Worksheet
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim StrSignature As String, FileExtStr As String, TempFilePath As String, TempFileName As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook, Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window, TempWindow As Window
    Dim shArray As Variant, arrSheet As Variant
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Emailer")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("GROW MONEY")
    Set rng = Nothing
    'Set rng2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:M34").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B18:I33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook 'easier to declare these to copy the sheets while going through the for each loop after filtering them
    Set Destwb = Workbooks.Add
    Sourcewb.Activate
    shArray = Array(Sheets("Tranche wise details"), Sheets("All products Deal limit status"), Sheets("Delinquency"), Sheets("GROW MONEY"))
    For Each arrSheet In shArray 'Filter before you do the copying
        Set sh = arrSheet
        Set nsh = Destwb.Sheets.Add
        nsh.Name = sh.Name
        If sh.AutoFilterMode Then 'autofilter is 'on'
            On Error Resume Next
            sh.ShowAllData 'clearing existing filters
            sh.Columns("M:M").Copy 'getting rid of the formulas first
            sh.Columns("M:M").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            sh.Columns("A:A").Copy
            sh.Columns("A:A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO" 'still not getting any errors here on the testfile
        End If
        sh.UsedRange.Copy nsh.Range("A1")
        nsh.UsedRange.Copy
        nsh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next arrSheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Destwb.Sheets(Destwb.Sheets.Count).Delete 'delete the sheet the workbook started with (depending on the language, these differ)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
            
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Destwb.Activate 'Destwb is ready to be mailed"

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = Sourcewb.Name


    strBody = "<font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"" color=""#1F497D"">" & "Dear All," & "<br> <br>" & _
           "Please find attached MIS Report as on " & Format(ws2.Range("B1").Value, "DD-MMM-YY") & "." & "<br><br>" & "</font>"
    
       
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    On Error Resume Next
           
With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
           
    With OutMail
        .To = ws.Range("C5").Value
        .CC = ws.Range("D5").Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ws.Range("E5").Value
        .HTMLBody = strBody & RangetoHTML(rng) '& RangetoHTML2(rng2) & vbNewLine '& StrSignature '& Signature
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
.Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

 

Function RangetoHTML2(rng2 As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng2.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML2 = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML2 = Replace(RangetoHTML2, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

My Test Sub: ONLY USED ON YOUR TESTFILE, THIS IS NOT THE FULL SUB

```
Sub TESTMIS_Mail()

    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, nsh As Worksheet
    Dim StrSignature As String, FileExtStr As String, TempFilePath As String, TempFileName As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook, Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window, TempWindow As Window
    Dim shArray As Variant, arrSheet As Variant
    
    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Destwb = Workbooks.Add
    Sourcewb.Activate
    shArray = Array(Sheets("Tranche wise details"), Sheets("All products Deal limit status"), Sheets("Delinquency"), Sheets("GROW MONEY"))
    For Each arrSheet In shArray 'Filter before you do the copying
        Set sh = arrSheet
        Set nsh = Destwb.Sheets.Add
        nsh.Name = sh.Name
        If sh.AutoFilterMode Then 'autofilter is 'on'
            On Error Resume Next
            sh.ShowAllData 'clearing existing filters
            sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO"
        End If
        sh.UsedRange.Copy nsh.Range("A1")
        nsh.UsedRange.Copy
        nsh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next arrSheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Destwb.Sheets(Destwb.Sheets.Count).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
            
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Destwb.Activate
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Notus, thanks for your prompt reply. As i don't have much knowledge of VBA, it would be great if you can help me with the complete code or that complete part of the code. when i tried this getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the "For Each sh In Sourcewb" line.

Comment: @Jeetu Edited my answer to put my code in your full code.

Comment: Thank you @Notus, have replaced the code but still getting  "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the "For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook" line. Please suggest.

Comment: My bad, I had Activeworkbook instead of Worksheets in the For Each, should be good now.

Comment: Thanks @Notus, seems something happened as I got another error message that "AutoFilter method or Range class failed" at the line "Else
            sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="GROW""

Comment: I've noticed one mistake where the ActiveSheet should be sh (edited in post) but I'm not getting any error in my testfile. Are you sure your headers up to the M column are populated? If there's one empty, i.e. C1 is empty, then you won't be able to put a criteria to Field:=13 (M).

Comment: yes there is no empty column from A1 to the last but the M1 has values for filter with the Vlookup formula from another sheet. Am attaching a sample file for your reference and the "Backend Calculation" sheet should also be skipped while copying.

Comment: Link to download file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSZyZipaPeZbLtiGHwk09CUkLldOVPGx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101035296842614210686&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Adjusted code to match your criteria, now it'll loop through an array of your specified sheets. There were no "GROW" values in your testfile so in case you don't want to filter on that, adjust the criteria to what you need.

Comment: thank you for your continued help but m still getting the error  "AutoFilter method or Range class failed" at the line "Else sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO". Just replace "GROW MONEY" with "UGRO" as I have shared sample data of "UGRO".

Comment: I've tried with your test file again (only my added code), since there is no GROW MONEY sheet in there, I added one with only enough columns to go to L:L and got the same error. After simply copying from "Tranche wise details", it worked as intended. 
Please check again if all sheets have the necessary columns and that your data isn't in a table but a range. See https://www.exceldemy.com/autofilter-method-of-range-class-failed/ for explanation around that.

Comment: could you please share your tested file so that i can figure out.

Comment: I've added my testsub that I used together with **your** shared testfile. For me it does what you requested.

Comment: Thanks @Notus for your help but as a newbie in VBA m still getting the error and stuck. I don't know how to crack it. Anyway much appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you able to see the sub work as intended on your test file at least? Maybe that'll make you see what's going wrong in your original.

Comment: have commented out "'sh.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="UGRO"" in Else and put "On Error GoTo 0" instead, the code is running and creates a new workbook with the selected sheet and data but the data is with auto filter mode and while removing the filter manually it is showing other data also (Apart from "UGRO"). And, getting a message at the line ".Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" that "You Can't past this here because the copy area and paster area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again".

Comment: Alright, I've adjusted the code to copy the sheets, keep the markup but paste as values after. Some of your code got adjusted because of this which is why I edited the full sub for you. I still don't know why you're getting an error on the Else part. If possible, can you show me how your original sheets look like?

Comment: thank you very much, it works now with the new sub changes and getting the filtered data into the new workbook. Only thing is that you have removed ws and ws2 from the sub which referred to the email body and subject. There I am getting errors and while I incorporated that into the code, the code is working but the data is not getting filtered into a new sheet. Getting the whole sheet without filtration.

Comment: I did not remove ws or ws2, are you perhaps copying from the TestSub rather than the full sub?

Comment: Extremely sorry, my bad, and yes you are right I have picked the testsub. Will try with the full sub and let you know. :)

Comment: hope you are doing well. Sorry for the delay in reply was tied up in so many things. The code is working fine except for auto-filter based on column M1, have noticed one thing, if I convert all the data into values (some columns has formulas) then it is working as expected but if I try to run the code on the actual workbook containing formulas in some sheets then it is not working. The code is creating a workbook but without filter. I believe you will help out with this too.

Comment: The only issue here should be the M column since it filters on those values, I added a quick copy paste as values for said column.

Comment: Hi @Notus, thanks but no luck with the formulated sheet. It's still not filtering the data, have to do it manually. I don't want to waste your time on it anymore. Will create the data, make a copy of the workbook, convert all the data into values and then run the code to send the emails with properly filtered data. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work out, but you're welcome for what I could do. Good luck in your further endeavors!